# ¿Cómo hacer un procesamiento con hilos tres pasos a la vez?

Tags: java, hilos

en esta ocasión estoy tratando de realizar el ejercicio de contar del 1 al 100 usando tres hilos,

- en el primer hilo van los números n
- en el segundo n+1
- en el tercero n+2

De manera que el primer hilo contará:

```
[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49, 52, 55, 58, 61, 64, 67, 70, 73, 76, 79, 82, 85, 88, 91, 94, 97, 100]
```

el segundo:

```
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 44, 47, 50, 53, 56, 59, 62, 65, 68, 71, 74, 77, 80, 83, 86, 89, 92, 95, 98]
```

el tercero:

```
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99]
```

El problema es que mis números no están saliendo en la secuencia planeada, sino que por ejemplo en el primero obtengo

```
[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 46, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 65, 68, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 83, 85, 88, 91, 97]
```

Este es mi código:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ThreadedCounting {

    public static void countInThreads(Counter counter) {

        ThreadFactory threadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3,threadFactory);//new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 3, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(3), threadFactory);


        List<Future> tasks = new ArrayList<>(3);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i += 3) {
            int icopy = i;

            tasks.add(executor.submit(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    counter.count(icopy);
                    try {
                        join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }));
            if (icopy != 100) {
                tasks.add(executor.submit(new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        counter.count(icopy + 1);
                        try {
                            join();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }));
                tasks.add(executor.submit(new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        counter.count(icopy + 2);
                        try {
                            join();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i+=3) {
            tasks.get(i);
            tasks.get(i+1);
            tasks.get(i+2);
            try {
                executor.awaitTermination(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Este es el código de la clase counter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Counter {
  private final List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
  private final Map<Integer, Long> threads = new HashMap<>();
  private final Map<Long, List<Integer>> threadNumbers = new HashMap<>();

  public synchronized void count(int i) {
    long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    numbers.add(i);
    threads.put(i, threadId);

    List<Integer> threadList = threadNumbers.get(threadId);
    if (threadList == null) {
      threadList = new ArrayList<>();
      threadNumbers.put(threadId, threadList);
    }
    threadList.add(i);
  }

  public List<Integer> getNumbers() {
    return new ArrayList<>(numbers);
  }

  public Set<Long> getThreadIds() {
    return new HashSet<>(threads.values());
  }

  public List<Integer> getNumbersInSameThreadAs(int i) {
    long threadId = threads.get(i);
    return new ArrayList<>(threadNumbers.get(threadId));
  }
}
```

Y por si alguien lo ocupa, este es el código de mi prueba unitaria:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ThreadedCountingTest {
   @Test
  public void the_correct_numbers_are_counted() {
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    ThreadedCounting.countInThreads(counter);

    Set<Integer> expected = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<Integer> actual = new HashSet<>(counter.getNumbers());

    assertEquals("The expected numbers were not generated", 
      expected, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void the_correct_numbers_are_counted_in_sequence() {
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    ThreadedCounting.countInThreads(counter);

    List<Integer> expected = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> actual = counter.getNumbers();

    assertEquals("The expected numbers were not generated in the right sequence", 
      expected, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void three_threads_are_used() {
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    ThreadedCounting.countInThreads(counter);

    assertEquals("The numbers are written in three different threads", 
      3, counter.getThreadIds().size());
  }

  @Test
  public void numbers_are_in_the_correct_threads() {
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    ThreadedCounting.countInThreads(counter);

    List<Integer> expected1 = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
      .filter(i -> i % 3 == 1)
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> expected2 = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
      .filter(i -> i % 3 == 2)
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> expected3 = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
      .filter(i -> i % 3 == 0)
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    assertEquals("Correct thread for 1, 4, 7...", 
      expected1, counter.getNumbersInSameThreadAs(1));
    assertEquals("Correct thread for 2, 5, 8...", 
      expected2, counter.getNumbersInSameThreadAs(2));
    assertEquals("Correct thread for 3, 6, 9...", 
      expected3, counter.getNumbersInSameThreadAs(3));
  }

}
```

¿Cómo puedo modificar mi código para que se realicen los cálculos en la secuencia correcta?

Comment: Creo que en cada iteración del bucle estás creando 3 hilos hasta que llegas a 100... es decir, creo que estás creando 100 hilos!

Comment: Como dice Pablo Lozano en cada iteración del bucle creas varios hilos, creo que estás buscando una lógica demasiado complicada, podrías hacer que cada tarea de hilo recibiese un array, así construirías primero los tres arrays y luego lanzar tres hilos.

Comment: @PabloLozano eso no es correcto, como verás si corres el programa solamente uso trs hilos exactamente, eso se debe al tamaño de mi pool

Answer (score 1):

Este algoritmo te permite realizar el conteo en el orden sugerido mediante el uso de hilos concurrentes. Puedes mejorarlo según tus requerimientos.

Estructura del HILO

```
public void hiloX(AtomicInteger conteo, int valorInicial){
    int DIFERENCIA = 0;

    Thread hilo = new Thread(() -> { System.out.println("Hilo "+valorInicial);
       int valor = valorInicial;
       while(conteo.get() <= 100){
        if(conteo.get() >= valor){
            if((conteo.get() - valor) == DIFERENCIA){  
                System.out.println("contador"+valorInicial+": "+valor);
                valor = conteo.getAndIncrement() + 3;
            }
        }
       }
    }, "Contador"+valorInicial);

    hilo.start();
}
```

Método para ejecutar la cantidad de hilos de interes

```
public void concurrenciaConteo(){
    AtomicInteger conteo = new AtomicInteger(1);
    this.hiloX(conteo, 1);
    this.hiloX(conteo, 2);
    this.hiloX(conteo, 3);
 }
```

Respuesta parcial.

```
Hilo 1
contador1: 1
Hilo 2
contador2: 2
Hilo 3
contador3: 3
contador1: 4
contador2: 5
contador3: 6
contador1: 7
contador2: 8
contador3: 9
contador1: 10
```

Código adaptado:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ThreadedCounting {
    public static void countInThreads(Counter counter) {
        AtomicInteger conteo = new AtomicInteger(1);
        hiloX(conteo, counter, 1);
        hiloX(conteo, counter, 2);
        hiloX(conteo, counter, 3);
    }

    public static void hiloX(AtomicInteger conteo, Counter counter, int valorInicial) {
        int DIFERENCIA = 0;


        Thread hilo = new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Hilo " + valorInicial);
            int valor = valorInicial;
            while (conteo.get() <= 100) {
                if (conteo.get() >= valor) {
                    if ((conteo.get() - valor) == DIFERENCIA) {
                        System.out.println("contador" + valorInicial + ": " + valor);
                        counter.count(valor);
                        valor = conteo.getAndIncrement() + 3;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, "Contador" + valorInicial);

        hilo.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: El código provisto algunas veces cuenta hasta 101

Comment: Es verdad. Debe ser por la forma concurrente en la que se accede a la variable atómica, es cuestión de dedicarle mas tiempo para afinar ese asunto aleatorio.